# issues installing apache cassandra on windows 7

Tags: windows, cassandra, nodetool

I've been trying to install apache cassandra on windows 7 64bit, i followed the video tutorial of the planetcassandra virtual training . when i try to execute on the terminal
*nodetool status* with the ops center opened it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin>nodetool status
Starting NodeTool
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/ca
ssandra/tools/NodeCmd : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.  Program will exit.
```

what could be the problem?can it be that i dont see any active node in the opscenter?
thanks in advance

Comment: You have to update JRE to 1.7 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 0):

```
     java -version
     javac -version
```

Both versions should be same.